# Amazon Workspaces doesn't scroll very well when using a macbook touchpad

Tags: macos, ubuntu, touchpad, amazon-web-services

I have a macbook pro and am using Ubunutu in Amazon workspaces. The scrolling using the two finger gesture only sometimes works. Seems to somewhat work when doing the whole gesture quickly including release. It works better but not great when plugging in a mouse.

Is there some way to fix or improve this in macos/ubunutu/workspaces?

Comment: So this is a Ubuntu virtual machine hosted on the Amazon platform? What software do you use to access it? Do you observe the same behavior accessing this VM using a different computer?

Comment: correct, the software is called "amazon workspaces", no works perfectly fine when accessing it from a windows computer (with mouse)